# npm install error: Package does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

When i run npm install, I get the following errors:

`npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/core@7.2.15 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/animations@7.2.15 wants @angular/core@7.2.15`

The installed version of @angular/core is indeed 7.2.15, but it's dependency @angular/animations says it needs version @angular/core 7.2.15

Any ideas?

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling @angular/core but still get the same error.

My package.json:

`{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui": "^1.0.17",
    "@ngrx/store": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.22",
    "aws-amplify-angular": "^2.1.9",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.3",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^5.2.4",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^7.2.1",
    "ngx-take-until-destroy": "^5.4.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.0.943",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@aws-amplify/cli": "^1.1.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.43",
    "@types/materialize-css": "^1.0.6",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}`

Comment: please post your full package.json

Comment: not sure but try ``npm update -g`` and see what it gives.

Comment: You are getting the error, because `@angular/core` is not being installed. The next package `@angular/animations` requires it and is complaining that it is not installed. Please include your `package.json` file.

Comment: I have updated my post to include package.json

Comment: Some times you can remove completely the ``node_modules`` directory and do ``npm install`` again, it may work. This way all the packages will be regenerated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try these commands:

1.update your npm `"npm install npm -g"`

2.update your angular `npm i -g @angular/cli`

3.clear your cache: `npm cache clear`

4.delete your node_modules, `rm -rf node_modules`,

5.Install it again , `npm install`.